# No more location available since IOS 9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, locationmanager, cllocation

my project won't work anymore since IOS release 9.0, in particular location (CLLocationManager).
My WiFi is Ok, I've corrected new errors due to new XCode version.

I've put some breakpoint, and the program never goes there :

```
func locationManager(didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]) {
    if (locationFixAchieved == false) {
        locationFixAchieved = true
        let locationArray = locations as NSArray
        let locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
        let coord = locationObj.coordinate

        print(coord.latitude)
        print(coord.longitude)
    }
}
```

More, I have these errors when I call this new method :

```
// Start location services
// NOTHING HAPPENS HERE
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
  // ERRORS ARE DISPLAYED WHEN THIS IS CALLED !!
  locationManager.requestLocation()
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}


2015-09-20 20:12:35.537 My fruits now[25113:3351106] XPC connection interrupted
2015-09-20 20:12:44.880 My fruits now[25113:3350891] Location to Allowed
2015-09-20 20:12:51.060 My fruits now[25113:3350891] *** Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager requestLocation], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreLocationFramework_Sim/CoreLocation-1861.0.9/Framework/CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.m:815
2015-09-20 20:12:51.072 My fruits now[25113:3350891] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didUpdateLocations:'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d69f65     __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108d19deb     objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106d69dca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000107459ae2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   CoreLocation                        0x000000010731f88c CLClientGetCapabilities + 10487
    5   My fruits now                       0x0000000106b3d2ee _TFC13My_fruits_now14ViewController15locationManagerfS0_FTCSo17CLLocationManager28didChangeAuthorizationStatusOSC21CLAuthorizationStatus_T_ + 814
    6   My fruits now                       0x0000000106b3d480 _TToFC13My_fruits_now14ViewController15locationManagerfS0_FTCSo17CLLocationManager28didChangeAuthorizationStatusOSC21CLAuthorizationStatus_T_ + 64
7   CoreLocation                        0x0000000107321849 CLClientGetCapabilities + 18612
    8   CoreLocation                        0x000000010731e583 CLClientGetCapabilities + 5614
    9   CoreLocation                        0x000000010731907d CLClientInvalidate + 923
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c9608c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c8bd15 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c8bac8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2472
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106c8ae98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bdd7ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010782c676    UIApplicationMain + 171
    16  My fruits now                       0x0000000106b46acd main + 109
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010986a92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Can you give me some advices, things to check, parameters to set, tips ... ?
Thank you !

Comment: Did you set the location manager's delegate to the class that responds to `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`?

Comment: In the meantime, I have searched further in the Apple Developper's Forum, I found the answer. Functions are not the same depending your target :

        #if os (iOS)  
        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {    }  
        #endif  
  
        #if os (watchOS)  
        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject])  {    }  
        #endif   

I have picked the first signature, and now it works again !!!
I breath again !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to implementation.

```
// Location Manager Delegate Methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
```